# CSS direction:rtl and top to bottom?

Tags: css, bidi

I'm using the following CSS to read a text from right to left:

```
.rtl { unicode-bidi:bidi-override;direction:rtl;width:300px;}

<span class="rtl">.tfel οt thgir mοrf daer si txet sihT</span>
```

It's part of an experimental site that would display all the text in the source code reversed, but readable to users.

It works well if I only have a sentence of text. However, once the length of the text is longer than the size of the element (300px in this case), the order of the sentences no longer works. For instance:

Source:

```
<div class="rtl"> .skaerb txet eht ,htgnel niatrec a tsaP .yllamron demrof era shpargarap eht rehtehw ees ot secnetnes lareves dedulcni ev'I dna ,tfel ot thgir morf daer si txet sihT</div>
```

Output:

(since I can't post images, there it is: http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/990715343.jpg )

As you can see, the first sentence, "This text is read from right to left" is aligned at the bottom, which means the order of the paragraph is wrong.

Is there another way to have to text flow normally from top to bottom and read from right to left?

Thank you

Comment: The text does flow normally from top to bottom. Forcing writing direction to be right to left does not change the vertical layout direction: data from the start of the element (“.skaerb txet eht ,htgnel...”) is collected until no more characters fit into the first line, then they are laid out right to left, then the next line is formatted etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems (as I explain in a comment) that you actually want text lines to be laid out bottom to top. There is currently no standard or cross-browser way to achieve that. On IE (version 8 and newer) you can use [`writing-mode: rl-bt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) (right to left, bottom to top). You might also wish to set `text-align: left`, since right-to-left direction implies by default right alignment, which is OK for right-to-left languages, but not so for tricks on writing direction for left-to-right languages.

Comment: The writing-mode property works great in Internet Explorer 8+. I understand that bidi-override and text-direction might not be suited for my experiment. Is there any CSS that would display all the content between two tags reversed (as to achieve what IE 8 does)?

Comment: @bidouillages, no, that would mean that other browsers implemented the same or similar, and that hasn’t happened. Probably you should look for a JavaScript solution (simple if the content is just text).